# Отключение триггера при прыжке

Tags: c#, unity3d, триггер, проверка

В общем, 4 удара работают последовательно по тригеру, но когда идет анимация прыжка и активируется триггер, при приземлении моментально воспроизводится удар(тригер).
Как можно сделать, что бы триггер работал только когда персонаж на земле, к примеру?
Код простой:

```
  if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse1))
    {
    anim.SetTrigger("Punch");
    }
```

Через `ResetTrigger` перестает работать комбо(

Comment: А если перед установкой триггера "Punch" проводить дополнительно проверку на текущую анимацию прыжка? И если анимация проигрывается, то триггер не активировать?

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался, просто перенес из скрипта управления триггер "IsGrounded".